# Cancel close WPF dialog - workaround for IsCancel bug

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a workaround for [a WPF bug that was raised on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4104c827-cb6d-43e6-bb44-c14200fb0a97/usercontrol-button-iscancel-not-honoring-ehandled-still-calls-dialogcancelcommand?forum=wpf) 3 years ago.  On the thread, the person who raised it suggested they could work around it by using "a Command instead of an EventHandler". I can't work out how to do that!

I have a WPF app that includes a wizard (following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31837/Creating-an-Internationalized-Wizard-in-WPF) well-regarded example).  Each page of the wizard has a Close button:

- The close click handler must pass the wizard result back to the parent app
- The button should be flagged with IsCancel so the Esc key triggers it
- The user must be asked "Are you sure you want to lose your changes?".

If the user says "No" then the wizard should not close.  However, because of the above bug, it closes regardless!

My view just has something like this:

```
<Button Text="Close" Click=OnCloseClick IsCancel="True"/>
```

My click handler:

```
private void OnCloseClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (UserConfirmsTheyWantToLoseChanges())
   {
      OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<MyWizardResult>(MyWizardResult.Canceled));
   }
   else
   {
      e.Handled = true;
   }
}
```

Can anyone give me a simple example of how this could be reworked using the Command pattern?

Comment: The bug you link to is specifically about setting e.handled to true to stop further processing of the event - you don't seem to do this so it does not seem relevant.

Comment: Do you have an implementation of the ICommand that you are currently using or what have you tried so far?

Comment: @PaulF good point, Paul!  I had tried that but hadn't included it in my example.  I've fixed that now.  The bug still manifests, sadly.

Comment: @mm8 no, sorry.  I've not used ICommand in WPF before (this is my first WPF project so apologies if I misuse some terminology, btw).  The examples I've seen all show the command being processed in the view model or a static class: I think I need to be in the view code-behind so I can call OnReturn.

Comment: So your current code actually works but you want to implement the MVVM pattern? Or what is your issue?

Comment: @mm8 with the code as shown above, if UserConfirmsTheyWantToLoseChanges() returns false, then the dialog closes anyway.  If I take the "IsCancel" out of the view, then it does not close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of handling the `Click` event for the `Button`, you could override the `OnClosing` method of the dialog window:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (UserConfirmsTheyWantToLoseChanges())
    {
        OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<MyWizardResult>(MyWizardResult.Canceled));
    }
    else
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Button Content="Close" IsCancel="True"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mm8.  This doesn't quite work for me because I'm using PageFunction which doesn't have OnClosing.  In the end, I added the above OnClosing to my main window -- but could not of course then call OnReturn from it, to communicate the Wizard result back to the parent app.  This was tolerable in my specific circumstance so I've gone with it.